# Can we derive an equation by a sequence of Gaussian reduction steps from the equations in the system?

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

I'm reading the Linear Algebra book by Jim Hefferon and I've encountered a difficult question to me. I don't understand the intention of the problem, therefore I don't know where to start solving it.

> Can we derive $6x - 9y + 5z = -2$ by a sequence of Gaussian reduction
>   steps from the equations in the system?
>
> $2x + y - z = 4$
>
> $6x - 3y + z = 5$

Comment: To put the question another way, is $6x-9y+5z=-2$ a linear combination of the other two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intention is quite straightforward: it is important to understand if an equation is independent from a system of equations or a logical consequence of it.

The problem is equivalent to the following question: is the vector $w=(6,-9,5,-2)$ a linear combination of the vectors $u=(2,1,-1,4)$ and $v=(6,-3,1,5)$. In other words, are there real numbers $x,y$ such that $w=xu+yv$. This leads to the following system of linear equations:

$2x+6y=6$

$x-3y=-9$

$-x+y=5$

$4x+5y=-2$

This has a unique solution: $x=-3, y=2$. 
So yes, the equation can be expressed from the system: multiply the first equation by $-3$ and the second by $2$, and add them up.

(If the above system of linear equations had no solution, it would mean that your equation is not expressible from the system. Think about it.)

Comment: Thanks Pongrácz! Your solution helps me a lots to move on with my study.